# forecast & plot multiple time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series, forecasting

i have some data i converted it to a time series for each week starting from 26/07/2017 and ends 05/03/2017 here's what i've got . 
i executed this command to get this

```
sensor <- msts(reshape2::dcast(data.post,sale.week~Reference,value.var='Quantite'),start = c(2016,30), seasonal.periods=c(7,52))
```

[Data](https://1fichier.com/?oeznri3w8x)

then i did this to forecast all the data

```
output <- lapply(sensor, function(x) forecast(tbats(x)))
```

but i don't know how to plot the quantity for each reference after forecasting 
i tried this but i'm getting

```
         ggplot(data = fc, aes(x=sale.year, y=Quantite, group=Reference)) + geom_line()
        Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class forecast
```

can anyone help me thank you in advance

Comment: I can't get a secure connection to your data, can you post the output of `dput(fc)` or a sub-sample?  How do you get `fc`, I only see your code upto `output` but that is not what you use for plotting.

Comment: hi friend forget about the last commad it has nothing to do with the data i've got mistaken after doing the lapply i have quantities arranged by reference for all the weeks from the 26/06/2017 to the end forecasted i want to plot them all how can i do that